# Create and Download Image of Linode to restore to Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V Environment

Tags: debian, hyper-v, windows-server, linode, server.transfer

We want to transfer a debian 6 install from linode to a Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V Environment.

1. How can I download a full image of my linode?
2. What format will the Windows Server need?

I mostly work in linux and I have been researching on how I might be able to accomplish this but I have not been able to find any good sources or tutorials on how it might be done. This topic isn't easily searchable. Any help would be appreciated. thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [This is Linode's step-by-step guide](https://library.linode.com/migration/ssh-copy) on how to create the image and transfer it to another machine over SSH.
2. Linode uses Xen for virtualization. You won't be able to run the Linode disk image directly on Hyper-V. In theory, you would need an intermediate VM (another Linux host OS running Xen within the Hyper-V which then loads the Linode image). I have never attempted this myself and I won't recommend it (i.e. nested VMs) either. One common solution is to do a clean OS install on your VM player and then copy/clone packages/configuration from Linode. Using a configuration management tool like [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_getting_started.html) would make the process a lot easier.